# Composite setLayout alignment

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, swt

I am using the org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite class and setLayout method.
I have two Composite objects

```
Composite mainContainer = new Composite(parent, SWT.NULL);
Composite secondContainer = new Composite(mainContainer, SWT.NULL);
```

Then I am using the setLayout method. When adding Text, Labels, Buttons, etc. It appears the Composite objects are left, and right. That is, secondContainer is on the left and mainContainer is on the right. I would like top and bottom. That is, where secondContainer is on top of mainContainer. I have not been able to achieve this so far using the setLayout and GridLayout class. Any idea how to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Which of the many layouts are you using?

Comment: org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridLayout

Comment: So maybe just an empty Composite and GridLayout will do the trick?

Comment: Please read [this](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Understanding-Layouts/Understanding-Layouts.htm). Then you should easily be able to solve your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try creating both mainContainer and secondContainer under the same Composite parent,
as parent's layout is set as either vertical RowLayout or vertical FillLayout.
Something like:

```
parent.setLayout(new RowLayout(SWT.VERTICAL));
Composite mainContainer = new Composite(parent, SWT.NULL);
Composite secondContainer = new Composite(parent, SWT.NULL);
```